# Regex to extract two digits from phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to take only 2 characters from my phone no.
I have used regex match `^\+55` and this will return the following example.

Phone No : `+5546342543`

Result : `46342543`

Expected Result was only `46`.

I don't want to use substring for the answer instead I want to extract that from the phone no with regex.

Comment: Why with regex when it's easy to solve with substring?

Comment: What are exact requirements? Get any two characters after `+55` at the beginning? Or 2 numbers after `+55`?

Comment: String operations are faster than regex in most cases... and you have a simple string.. why would you use regex over substring ?

Comment: I guess the real-life problem is a bit different: just drop a comment under my answer if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you used - `^\+55` - matches a literal `+` in the beginning of the string and two `5`s right after.

`46` is the substring that appears right after the initial `+55`. In some languages, you can use a [*look-behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (see [example](https://regex101.com/r/fC5jR8/2)) to match some text preceded with another.

JavaScript has no look-behind support, so, you need to resort to [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

You can use `string#match` or `RegExp#exec` to obtain that captured text marked with round brackets:

```js
var s = '+5546342543';
if ((m=/^\+55(\d{2})/.exec(s)) !== null) {
    document.write(m[1]);
  }
```

This example handles the case when you get no match.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
'+5546342543'.match(/^\+55(\d{2})/)[1];
```

Comment: @Prabhakaran If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you want

```
"+5546342543".match(/^\+55(.*)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem ?

```
phoneNumber = "+5546342543"
phone = phoneNumber.substr(3) // returns "46342543" 
twoDigits = phoneNumber.substr(3,2) // returns "46"
```

Using the `substr()` method as quoted :

> The `substr()` method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.

Syntax: `str.substr(start[, length])`

Source : [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)